# What character encoding is this FoxPro database?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, codepages

Okay, so we have an extremely old FoxPro database. I have trouble figuring out the correct encoding for the data.

So there are the bytes `0x8e 0x99 0x9a 0x84 0x94 0x81 0x40 0x80` which I know are the characters `Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü @ €`.

```
0x8e = Ä in CP-850
0x99 = Ö in CP-850
0x9a = Ü in CP-850
0x84 = ä in CP-850
0x94 = ö in CP-850
0x81 = ü in CP-850
0x40 = @ in CP-850
```

So that *could* be CP-850 or CP-858.

But then there is byte `0x80` that I know represents the Euro symbol `€`. However, CP-850 does not contain the Euro symbol. CP-858 does, but not at that position.

If you look at Windows-1252, the Euro symbol is at position 0x80, so that would match. However, the characters `Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü` are at different positions.

```
0x80 = € in Windows-1252
```

I have not found one codepage or encoding that would comprise all of the above, that is why I want to ask what codepage or encoding this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently it was customary to programmatically set the currency symbol to char 128 or rather 0x80.

`SET CURRENCY TO CHR(128)`

So what normally would have been "Ç" then became "€".